# Twitter Bootstrap: make a 2x2 grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span3"></div>
      <div class="span3"></div>
      <div class="span3"></div>
      <div class="span3"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

By default, this div.span* spans the entire width of the screen, like this:

```
[x][x][x][x]
```

At a certain screen width, I want this to appear in a 2x2 grid, like this:

```
[x][x]
[x][x]
```

How do I do this?

Comment: can you give me the css you have already for container-fluid, row-fluid and span3?  I'll make a jfiddle for you.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah: Its the default selectors available in twitter bootstrap library.

Comment: http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Comment: Bootstrap is a constantly changing project, it would be a lot more helpful if the relevant CSS was here as well, especially for those of us who don't use it.

Comment: The linked TB CDN + the mark up I gave will have everything I have.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry about my earlier attempts, I did not fully understand your question:

The thing which you are trying with bootstrap is not really possible unless you go for your own @media selectors. There is a library called [Neat](http://neat.bourbon.io/). I think this is the [example](http://neat.bourbon.io/examples/) you are looking for.

EARLIER ATTEMPTS:

---

Try this, from [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">A</div>
        <div class="span6">B</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">C</div>
        <div class="span6">D</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This should give you the following result:

```
[A][B] 
[C][D]
```

Well that's a lot of `div`s. Not really sure if this can be made lighter.

---

Comment: I believe the OP only wants two rows *at a certain screen width*.

Comment: I do not want to change the mark up as I need it to be in a single horizontal layout for the wider screens.

Comment: So, you need not just a row-fluid, but a library which supports column-fluid as well?

Comment: The simplest and most efficient way is to change the width of the span3 class based on different browswer widths using media queries.  That way he can have it go from a single row of four, to two rows of two columns, to a single column of four with minimal code - using media queries.  That way he can keep his framework the way it already is and gain the functionality he is looking for. Why would you want to include huge libraries of css code just to achieve one simple thing?

Comment: I'm using Twitter Bootstrap already. Yes, I will be using media queries. I'm just wondering how to change the layout to that 2x2 grid.

Comment: I guess what RaphaelRafatpanah has answered is best. @RaphaelRafatpanah: Point taken.

Answer (score 1):

The original question appears to be for an older edition of bootstrap.

Here's what solves the issue neatly in Bootstrap 3 markup.  The key element is the `clearfix` div that affects `xs` and `sm` viewports [typical use case]. (`sm` not included in example below).

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-3</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-3</div>

  <!-- Add the extra clearfix for only the required viewport -->
  <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-3</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-3</div>
</div>
```

> [via getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets)

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 options that are responsive without the need for media queries.  Resize the windows to see how they react.

CSS Columns:

http://jsfiddle.net/88t4L/

```
.row-fluid {
    columns: 2 8em;
}
```

Here, the columns must be at least 8em wide, but if there's room for all of them to appear in a row, it will do so.

http://caniuse.com/#search=columns

CSS Flexbox:

http://jsfiddle.net/88t4L/1/

```
.row-fluid {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.row-fluid .span3 {
    flex: 1 0 8em; /* grow equally, don't shrink, preferred width of 8em */
}
```

http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox